# How to know when my notification is cleared via Clear button?

Tags: android, notifications

I have created a notification and added a `PendingIntent` so that the notification is closed when the notification is selected in expanded view.

My problem is that when the user clicks the `Clear` button to remove all notifications I am not notified and I need to perform some cleanup when my notification is killed.

`FLAG_NO_CLEAR` would enable me to ignore the `Clear` button and keep my notification but I'd prefer to have my `Intent` triggered correctly to allow cleanup.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for the [deleteIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#deleteIntent) field of the [`Notification`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) class.