# Retrieving information from one's own previously posted notifications

Tags: android, notifications

Is it possible for applications to retrieve information from one of their previously posted notifications? If so, how?

Comment: What are you even asking? What do you mean by access?

Comment: I mean to get or retrieve it (in code) so that I may read or use the information it contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API does not offer any functionality to *retrieve* information from a notification. You cannot, for instance, get a list of all notifications your application has created, you would have to create and manage such a list yourself.

See this post: [Check if my application's notification is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286817/android-check-if-my-applications-notification-is-running)

That post also provides a link to this post: [How to know when my notification is cleared via Clear button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666887/how-to-know-when-my-notification-is-cleared-via-clear-button)
Which may be of some interest if you would like to be notified when the user does a "Clear" on all notifications.

You created them, you should know how many are showing and what they are displaying and when they are being displayed. I don't mean to sound derogatory, this is just what the API is assuming in this case.

Comment: actually you can, but that requires being an AccessibilityService and being selected as a active accessibility service.