# In Android how do I get the currently displayed notification for a given notification id?

Tags: android, notifications

My intention is to display a notification with a personalised icon. However, if a notification with the same id is already displayed and then I need to add a new notification with the same id, my program will instead prepare a "stacked" version of the notification where the icon is changed to some generic icon and the notification content shows excerpts from the last and current notifications. Similar to how Gmail does when there are multiple emails.

To implement that I need to check if there are notifications of my app, currently displayed. I do not see any API to retrieve my own notifications.

I cannot simply cache the notification details that I have displayed till now, since in that case I need to know when they will be dismissed by the user, and update my cache accordingly. I also do not see any API to listen for dismiss events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you observe the `gmail` app notification behaviour properly u will notice that even when u dismiss one notification gmail shows you the same notification again in the list when a new notification comes. It looks to me that gmail is relying on `total unread/unopened messages` rather than keeping a cache of notifications.

There is no direct api for ur suggested SDK version. You need to fallback to ur own implementation. However, there is a way to know if a already showed notification was dismissed - [How to know when my notification is cleared via Clear button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666887/how-to-know-when-my-notification-is-cleared-via-clear-button)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with android 4.3 upwards now

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#getActiveNotifications()

Comment: I need to support minimum SDK 10. Do we have this API in support library?